# Kubernetes: run a job on node reboot only once

Tags: kubernetes, cron, jobs, kubernetes-pod, kubelet

Is there a way to run a job only once upon machine reboot in Kubernetes?

Thought of running a cronjob as static pod but seems kubelet does not like it.

Edit: Based on the replies, I'd like to clarify. I'm only looking at doing this through native Kubernetes. I'm ok writing a cronjob in Kubernetes but I need this to run only once and upon node reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your platform.

For example, in AWS, ec2 instance has `user_data` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

It will run commands on Your Linux/Windows Instance at Launch

You should be fine to find the similar solutions for other cloud providers or on-premise servers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should consider using [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/):

> A `DaemonSet` ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod. As
>   nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are
>   removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a
>   `DaemonSet` will clean up the Pods it created.

That way you could create a container with a job that would be run from a `DaemonSet`.

Alternatively you could consider [DaemonJob](https://github.com/AmitKumarDas/metac/tree/master/examples/daemonjob#daemonjob):

> This is an example `CompositeController` that's similar to Job, except
>   that a pod will be scheduled to each node, similar to `DaemonSet`.

Also there are:

- [Kubebuilder](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder#kubebuilder)

> Kubebuilder is a framework for building Kubernetes APIs using custom
>   resource definitions (CRDs).

and:

- [Metacontroller](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/metacontroller#metacontroller)

> Metacontroller is an add-on for Kubernetes that makes it easy to write
>   and deploy custom controllers in the form of simple scripts.

But the first option that I have provided would be easier to implement in my opinion.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CronJob for this. It takes the same format as normal cron scheduler on linux. 
Besides the usual format (minute / hour / day of month / month / day of week) that is widely used to indicate a schedule, cron scheduler also allows the use of `@reboot`. 
This directive, followed by the absolute path to the script, will cause it to run when the machine boots.

Comment: `@reboot` will not work. see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/96912